# Flutter : Local notifications not working on iOS release mode

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm using the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package to display notifications in and outside the app (background mode).
Everything is working as expected on Android (debug + release) and iOS debug mode but, strangely, local notifications are not displayed in background mode for iOS release.

I don't know why the iOS release mode behaves differently, any thoughts?

Thanks.

What I already checked:

- use of the latest version of the flutter_local_notifications package (v16.1.0)
- checking "Signing & Capabilities" for both debug and release mode (Background modes : fetch, remote notifications)

My Notification class:

```js
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class ReceivedNotification {
  ReceivedNotification({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.body,
    required this.payload,
  });

  final int id;
  final String? title;
  final String? body;
  final String? payload;
}

/// A notification action which triggers a App navigation event
const String navigationActionId = 'id_3';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void notificationTapBackground(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  // ignore: avoid_print
  print('notification(${notificationResponse.id}) action tapped: '
      '${notificationResponse.actionId} with'
      ' payload: ${notificationResponse.payload}');
  if (notificationResponse.input?.isNotEmpty ?? false) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print(
        'notification action tapped with input: ${notificationResponse.input}');
  }
}

class NotificationService {
  //Singleton pattern
  static final NotificationService _notificationService =
      NotificationService._internal();
  factory NotificationService() {
    return _notificationService;
  }
  NotificationService._internal();

  /// Streams are created so that app can respond to notification-related events
  /// since the plugin is initialised in the `main` function
  final StreamController<ReceivedNotification>
      didReceiveLocalNotificationStream =
      StreamController<ReceivedNotification>.broadcast();

  final StreamController<String?> selectNotificationStream =
      StreamController<String?>.broadcast();

  //instance of FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/iclauncher');

    //Initialization Settings for iOS devices
    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
          (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
        didReceiveLocalNotificationStream.add(
          ReceivedNotification(
            id: id,
            title: title,
            body: body,
            payload: payload,
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    final InitializationSettings settings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      settings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
          (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
        switch (notificationResponse.notificationResponseType) {
          case NotificationResponseType.selectedNotification:
            selectNotificationStream.add(notificationResponse.payload);
            break;
          case NotificationResponseType.selectedNotificationAction:
            if (notificationResponse.actionId == navigationActionId) {
              selectNotificationStream.add(notificationResponse.payload);
            }
            break;
        }
      },
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
    );
  }

  Future<NotificationDetails> _notificationDetails() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel ID',
      'channel name',
      playSound: true,
      priority: Priority.high,
      importance: Importance.high,
    );

    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);

    return notificationDetails;
  }

  Future<void> showNotification({
    required int id,
    required String title,
    required String body,
  }) async {
    final details = await _notificationDetails();
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(id, title, body, details);
  }
}
```

Comment: could you share your code here..I think the problem is in your class

Comment: @AbuSayed, I shared my notification class. And I call the `showNotification` method in my code when needed.

Comment: Please check my class and update your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your iOS initialisation issue create your problem . I am using this class..so please check this and update your code.Most importantly  check iOSinitialization section.

```
class LocalNotificationService {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void initialize() {
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/transparent_othership"),
      iOS: IOSInitializationSettings(),
    );

    _notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (String? body) async {
      if (body != null) {
        final json = jsonDecode(body);
        json.toString().log();
      }
    });
  }

  static void display(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      // final sound = "notification_sound.wav";
      final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;

      final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'channel ID',
         'channel name',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
          enableLights: false,
          playSound: true,
          enableVibration: false,
          showWhen: false,
          // sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(sound.split('.').first),
        ),

        //we need to create Resouces folder in
        //runner then put the wav file in there
        iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(presentSound: true),
      );

      String title = "";
      String body = "";
      message.toString().log();
      message.notification.toString().log();
      message.data.toString().log();
      if (message.notification != null) {
        title = message.notification?.title ?? "";
        body = message.notification?.body ?? "";
      } else {
        final responseBody = jsonDecode(message.data['body']);
        title = responseBody['title'] ?? "";
        body = responseBody['body'];
      }

      await _notificationsPlugin.show(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        notificationDetails,
        payload: message.data.isEmpty ? null : message.data['body'],
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To emulate push notifications for iOS, you need to use a physical device and Xcode instead of Android/Visual Studio.

Xcode will give you all of the feedback you need, like an AI response.

Without a physical device and Xcode, you could have perfectly written code, but you won't get the emulation.